# Dropdown navigation bar keyframes animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

So here's just a simplified version of what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/mpgLLq9j/30/

Basically when I hover over 'Dogs', I want the submenu to slide down like the animation says. Here's the code I used for that:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
    0%   { top: 10; }
    100% { top: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInDown {
    0%   { top: 10; }
    100% { top: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes slideInDown {
    0%   { top: 10; }
    100% { top: 0; }
}
@keyframes slideInDown {
  0%   { top: 10; }
  100% { top: 0; }
}

.dog:hover ul.menu-2{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  animation: slideInDown 1s;
  -webkit-animation: slideInDown;
}
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to use slidein would be to use jquery animate:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mpgLLq9j/36/

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $(".dog").hover(function(){$(".menu-2",this).stop().slideDown();},function(){$(".menu-2",this).stop().slideUp();});
    });
</script>
```